# php grabbing data from javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Apparently i try to save the data into the mysql, but it didnt work.. Anyone help?

create_users.php

```
<form method="post" action="checkAvailability.php">
 <script>
    var macs = { 
    getMacAddress : function() 
    { 
        document.macaddressapplet.setSep( "-" ); 
        return (document.macaddressapplet.getMacAddress()); 
    }}jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
        var mac = macs.getMacAddress();  
        $.get('/checkAvailability.php?mac=' + mac, function() { alert('yeah done'); }) 
    }); 
</script>  



<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(macs.getMacAddress());
</script>
    </form>
```

checkAvailability.php

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbname = 'registration';
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$mac = $_GET['mac'];
$mac = mysql_real_escape_string($mac);
$sql = "INSERT INTO test(mac) VALUES ('$mac')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "didn't work". And what is `macs`? It is not a standard object and not defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: Add some echo's to see what's going on and call your script directly from the browser. Your problem could be anywhere from the mac var being empty to your mysql connection not being made to the database.

Comment: hmm.. okay i edit my post again.. Pls help..

Comment: Ah I see you went with my brief code. It will probably require some error checking etc

Comment: error checking as in?? which part? i thought it would be a simple coding..

Answer (score 4):

You are calling "create_users.php" in your $.get() method instead you should be calling "checkAvailability.php"..

And try this for your client side form:

```
var macs = {
getMacAddress : function()
{
    document.macaddressapplet.setSep( "-" );
    return (document.macaddressapplet.getMacAddress());
}}jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var mac = macs.getMacAddress(); 
    $.get('/checkAvailability.php?mac=' + mac, function() { alert('yeah done'); })
});
```

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that =x

Comment: throw a quick and dirty echo `mysql_error()` after `mysql_query()`. Also, have you connected to your database?

Comment: Going to go with my original comment, try calling it directly from the browser: http://yoursite.com/checkAvailability.php?mac=555  Add some echo statements to check your SQL and a `or die(mysql_error());` after the query. If the direct call puts a record in your database, then at least you know the problem is on the front-end.

Comment: hmm.. i tried to call it manually from the browser, and it works... but how come it doesnt call up properly...

Comment: is my form having this issue here?

Comment: I have edited my answer.. I suppose you are using a java applet to populate the macs variable, it would be logical to call the related function on document load.

Comment: hmm...tried, still not working... will my checkAvailability url display the MAC Address?

and a simple document.write(macs.getMacAddress()) also not working anymore..

Comment: The location of jQuery(document).ready( is not allowing the document.write(macs.getMacAddress()) to work. Please use the updated script.

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer... 

but still didnt work, i did a check on mysql.. the mac column is empty..